# FB.Api not fetch anything

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

It's the first time I create a Login With Facebook, and I don't know why I can't get any data. Everything goes fine until the dialog to obtain permissions appears; When the user click on "Accept" button I get this error:

```
GET https://www.facebook.com/impression.php/f3962c3d68/?api_key='API_KEY'….oauth%22%2C%22display%22%3A%22popup%22%7D%2C%22source%22%3A%22jssdk%22%7D
```

Here's how I have implemented the Login:

```
function facebookLogin() {

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

                  if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // connected
                    getProfileData();

                  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    //app not_authorized
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response && response.status === 'connected') {
                            getProfileData();
                        }
                    },{scope:'email,user_photos'});

                  } else {
                    // not_logged_in to Facebook
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response && response.status === 'connected') {
                            getProfileData();
                        }
                    },{scope:'email,user_photos'});
                  }
            });
        }


        function getProfileData(){
            FB.api("/me", function(response){
                if(response && !response.error)
                {
                    var name=response.name;
                    var email=response.email;
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log(response.error);
                }
            });
        }
```

API Initialization I think it's fine, I don't get errors about that on the console. Hope you can help me with this. Thanks in advance :D.

UPDATE:
Rarely, printing on the console (I haven't tried it, it was a random thought xD), it fetches the data, but the error stills.

Comment: That's not an error, just an URL...

Answer (score 0):

I just found that funny function called "pingFacebook" on the "fb" module from npm.

It's not the same library as you are using, but it's also facebook related.

it basically posts you appId to a page on facebook, which i can't understand why is necessary.

https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-node-sdk/issues/85

I created an issue for that in hope to get an answer.